# Where can I found 'Go to detailed view' button in Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am reading '[Build RESTful APIs with ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api)' article.

I keyed F12, opened Developer Tools window in Edge but I could not find Go to detailed view button. Can you please tell me how to find it, or if it was removed because it is Edge, can you please tell me what button the same is with Go to detailed view button?

[instructions]
[image: instructions]

[actual Developer Tool]
[image: actual Developer Tool]

Answer (score 0):

In Edge devtools, you just need to select the request which you want to check, then you can get the interface similar to that in IE. Somthing like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StnzN.png).